# How to pass touch event to parent view if event is not scrolling View Pager

Tags: android-viewpager, android-touch-event

My view pager is in CoordinatorLayout

If touch event does not do any scrolling to ViewPager (horizontal scrolling), I would like to pass that event to RelativeLayout.